# How to alternate empty space color in QTreeWidget?

Tags: qt, colors, qtreewidget, alternate, alternating

If I type this code

```
myTree->setAlternatingRowColors(true);
myTree->setStyleSheet("QTreeWidget{alternate-background-color: red;background: green;}");
```

colors of rows are interleaves. But if a QTreeWidget is not full there is an empty space which has green color. Is there a posibility to brush this space with red when the last row is green?

P.S.

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QTreeWidget>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QWidget *mainWidget = new QWidget();
    mainWidget->resize(200,100);
    QTreeWidget *myTree = new QTreeWidget(mainWidget);
    myTree->resize(200,100);

    QTreeWidgetItem *newTreeItem;
    newTreeItem = new QTreeWidgetItem(myTree);
    newTreeItem->setText(0,"leaf_01");
    newTreeItem = new QTreeWidgetItem(myTree);
    newTreeItem->setText(0,"node_02");
    newTreeItem = new QTreeWidgetItem(newTreeItem);
    newTreeItem->setText(0,"leaf_03");

    myTree->setAlternatingRowColors(true);
    myTree->setStyleSheet("QTreeWidget{alternate-background-color: red; background: green;}");

    mainWidget->show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

[image]

Comment: I see that the colors are always alternating, maybe there are some items that are hidden where the alternate color is. If not, then provide a [mcve]

Comment: @eyllanesc, I guess he is trying to colorize empty space below the rows depending on the color of the last row. There could be even or odd number of them, that's why simple alternating doesn't help

Comment: @MasterAler The empty space is considered as an item and it is painted with an alternate color

Comment: @eyllanesc, you must be right, but I'll dare clarify the question with something the guy didn't provide (should be part of a question, really) -- https://drive.google.com/file/d/17bWUeTHy5hljEozkaI78AUPeGEXXN97q/view?usp=sharing. Here, the right QTreeWidget "extends" green color, he doesn't like it. Surely, widget behaves as it is supposed to, though.

Comment: @ eyllanesc, Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example is ready.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried to redefine the drawRow of the QTreeWidget.

It working quite well but is it a good practice?

```
void myTreeWidget::drawRow(QPainter *p, const QStyleOptionViewItem &opt, const QModelIndex &idx) const
{   
    if(itemFromIndex(idx)) {
        if(!itemBelow(itemFromIndex(idx))) {

            int counter = 0;
            QTreeWidgetItem *currentItem = topLevelItem(0);
            if(currentItem) {
                while(itemBelow(currentItem)) {
                    currentItem=itemBelow(currentItem);
                    counter = counter + 1;
                }
            }

            if(counter % 2) {
                p->setBrush(oddColor);
            } else {                
                p->setBrush(evenColor);
            }

            QRect itemRect = visualRect(idx);
            QRect emptySpace = this->rect();
            emptySpace.setTop(itemRect.y()+itemRect.height());
            p->setPen(Qt::transparent);
            p->drawRect(emptySpace);
        }
    }

    QTreeWidget::drawRow(p, opt, idx);
}
```

Comment: As far as I see, you can't achieve what you wnat with QSS, so either you reimplement `drawRow` (which would definitely make sense if you've used QTreeView, so that the solution could be easily reused. But looks fine with QTreeWidget, too) or you add/remove an empty fake QTreeWidgetItem depending on the row count parity (odd/even). The latter is quite a hacky solution, not a clean, imho, but also could be improved to become reusable. The choise is upon you.